# Software-Design Issues

Tags: web-services, swing, jsf, client-server, netty

I'm planing to build a software in client-server-design. Technology should be Java.

Server should have a communication layer for web-services (e.g. RESTful Jersey), RMI, JSF.

Clients can be: Fatclients in Swing or Browser clients in JSF.

In my focus are JBoss Netty for the server, Jersey looks much more simple but Netty would have more other interfaces which could be interesting too. Does Netty offer something for RMI?

I read somewhere that JSF and RESTful doesn't fit together. Are there web-service implementations which fit to a JSF implementation like icefaces?

Thanks!

Comment: Wow, this question would win any buzzword bingo contest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest to use Spring Framework. Using it you can implement RMI, REST etc over the same service implementation and it is very simple to do. On top of it your design will benefit  from Dependency Injection paradigm used by Spring.

Check it out at http://www.springsource.org/about

Comment: Spring could be something but I'm afraid that it's a overhead, quite a big piece of software.

Comment: Don't be. In Spring you only use/load what you need.